# jQuery detect select in radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build form with radio buttons, where i need to detect if all radio has bee selected.

It's quite easy function .change. In my situation:

```
    $('input:radio').change(function() {
    alert($('[name|="pyt10"]:checked').val() + " / " + $('[name|="pyt11"]:checked').val() + " / "+ 
})
```

But here is small issue - i have 3 groups of radios. When i select first radio, alert shows me, that all fields are udefined, after second select first radio has value, but second is still undefined, and so on.

It means, that my alert shows radio value before change, not after.

What should i do to write radio value after select ?

Comment: Since you are using `:checked`, it will only select the element by name if it's checked. You might want to take it off.

Comment: I want to take checked value, but what is a problem - radio is not selected - default value "undefined", i select it the value is changing into "1", but alert still shows "undefined", after second select it shows "1"... Alert value is one step behind, it shows value before changes...

Answer (score 2):

For your immediate problem, "where i need to detect if all radio has bee selected.", you can use this:

```
var radios = $('input:radio').on("click", function () {
    alert(radios.length === radios.filter(":checked").length);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VWrzN/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can also loop through the inputs:

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
        myArray = new Array();
        $('input:radio').each(function(){
            this.checked ? myArray.push(this.value) : myArray.push("notChecked");
        })
        alert(myArray.join("/"))
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not far off. instead of alerting

```
$('[name|="py10"]:checked
```

Make sure it's checked

```
if ($('[name|="py10"]').is(':checked')) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: if you have wrapped (or can wrap) your radio groups with a form tag you can check if as many values as groups are set:

```
$('#radios').on('change', ':radio', function () {
    var form = $(this).closest('form'),
        full = form.serializeArray().length == 2;
    console.log(full);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aV8MJ/1/)

`form.serializeArray()` will return an array with each radio group value if one radio button of that group is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at just the alert in the javascript you have a syntax error since you have not closed it with a trailing `)`

Try the following

```
$('input:radio').change(function () {
var $this = $(this);
var group1Val =  $('[name|="pyt10"]:checked').val();
var group2Val =  $('[name|="pyt11"]:checked').val();
var group3Val =  $('[name|="pyt12"]:checked').val();   


$('.output').html(
    'Value of radio button clicked: '+ $this.val() + '<br><br>'
    + 'Value of radio button checked for group 1: '
    + group1Val + ' <br>'
    + 'Value of radio button checked for group 2: '
    + group2Val + ' <br>'
    + 'Value of radio button checked for group 3: '
    + group3Val + ' <br>'
);

//alert($('[name|="pyt10"]:checked').val() + " / " + $('[name|="pyt11"]:checked').val() + " / "+
});
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pV8yg/) for the above.